# How can i sum(color = ‘red’) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i run sql on pgadmin but this query is error

```
Select sum(color = ‘red’) from table
```

How can i query sum of color is red on postgresql and not like this:

```
Select count(color) from table where color = ‘red’
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't sum a string... but I think what you want is:

```
Select sum(CASE WHEN color = ‘red’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Select sum( (color = 'red')::int )
from t;
```

Or using `filter`:

```
select count(*) filter (where color = 'red')
from t;
```

Comment: I can’t believe I hadn’t come across filter before - so useful!